# Keep visitors from accessing wp-admin login page

Tags: wordpress, admin

I'm running a site with Wordpress and would like to keep my visitors from accessing the admin login page by simply going to "domain.com/wp-admin". I've looked into allowing specific IPs, but I'm always working at in different locations on different networks, so any static solutions are out of the question.

I'm thinking about just putting in a couple of redirects, but I'm not entirely sure that would be the best, most secure solution.

*Note: I've looked into a couple of plugins, but they only limit what users can do once in the admin panel. I'd like to stop visitors and hackers from getting in altogether.

Answer (score 2):

A better option is to put the restrictions at the Apache level, so that WP is not involved at all in the access decisions. A regular HTTP password might be suitable, e.g.

```
<Location /wp-admin/>
   Require valid-user
   AuthType Basic
   etc...
</Location>
```

and you could combine this with a [`Satisfy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#satisfy) directive so that the places you KNOW you're logging in from are explicitly allowed in via IP matching, and leave the password prompt for "everything else".